# MSSQL - Create records for entries that don't exist in the last 7 days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.NET website with a C# back-end using MSSQL SQL Server 2008 for its content.

I have written the following stored procedure which checks for any records within the last 7 days and then returns what it finds.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbuser].[GetResponses] 
    (
    @QUEST_ID int
    )   
AS
    SELECT DateAdded, SUM(Responses) AS responseCount
    FROM ActiveResponses
    WHERE @QUEST_ID = QuestionnaireID AND DateAdded >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 6,0)
    GROUP BY DateAdded
    RETURN
```

My problem here is that if no record exists for any of those last 7 days then my method over on the website back-end side will fail as it required 7 records. For example:

Lets say I have the following records in my table

```
-DateAdded--------Responses
2012-02-12           4
2012-02-11           5
2012-02-10           8
2012-02-08           7
2012-02-07           3
```

Notice that there are no records for both **2012-02-13**(today) and **2012-02-09**

How can I create an SQL statement that checks the last 7 days for the number of responses and if **no** records are found for any one of those days it creates a record with a response of **0** in the correct position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good application of a numbers table (ex: http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/tblnumbers.aspx)

Assuming you have a numbers table `dbo.Nums` that has at least 6 numbers in it, you can try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    [Date] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Dates
(
    [Date]
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()) - ([n] - 1), 0)
FROM
    [dbo].[Nums] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    [n] < 7

SELECT
    [Date],
    ISNULL(SUM([Responses]), 0) AS [responseCount]
FROM
    #Dates AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ActiveResponses AS a
ON
    a.[DateAdded] = d.[Date]
WHERE
    @QUEST_ID = QuestionnaireID
ORDER BY
    [Date] ASC
```

Comment: I don't have a separate table for numbers. The number of responses are contained in their own table (ActiveResponses). This is the table which I want to perform the check and select on. Do I need multiple tables in order to do this?

Comment: If you check out the link I have in the response, the `Nums` table is a simple single column table. It's only purpose is to assist in queries which have requirements similar to yours. If you are averse to creating the `Nums` table, you can directly insert all 7 days into the temp `#Dates` table above and reach the same result...

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates getting summary data for each day in a week, even if some of the days have no data:

```
declare @Data as table ( DateAdded date, Responses int )
insert into @Data ( DateAdded, Responses ) values ( '2/10/2012', 5 ), ( '2/13/2012', 9 )

; with James as (
  select cast( SysDateTime() as date ) as StartOfDay, 7 as DaysLeft
  union all
  select DateAdd( d, -1, StartOfDay ), DaysLeft - 1
    from James
    where DaysLeft > 1
  )
  select J.StartOfDay, DateAdd( ms, -3, cast( DateAdd( day, 1, J.StartOfDay ) as DateTime ) ) as EndOfDay, Coalesce( D.Responses, 0 ) as Responses
    from James as J left outer join
      @Data as D on D.DateAdded = J.StartOfDay
    order by J.StartOfDay desc
```

Left as an exercise is mating this with your questionnaire data.

Note that the time closest to midnight represented by DateTime values is 3ms before midnight.  You can use the StartOfDay and EndOfDay values to drop any DateAdded into the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a table variable with the last seven dates and include it with your query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbuser].[GetResponses] 
    (
    @QUEST_ID int
    )   
AS
DECLARE @i INT=0;
DECLARE @today DATE=getdate();
DECLARE @last7 TABLE(DateAdded DATE);

WHILE @i>-7 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @last7 VALUES (DATEADD(DAY,@i,@today));
    SET @i -= 1;
END

;WITH a AS (
    SELECT ar.DateAdded, count(ar.Responses) as responseCount
    FROM ActiveResponses ar
    INNER JOIN @last7 z ON z.DateAdded=ar.DateAdded
    WHERE @QUEST_ID = ar.QuestionnaireID
    GROUP BY ar.DateAdded
)
SELECT DateAdded=ISNULL(a.DateAdded,z.DateAdded)
, responseCount=ISNULL(a.responseCount,0)
FROM @last7 z
LEFT JOIN a ON a.DateAdded=z.DateAdded;
RETURN;
GO
```

Results:

```
DateAdded  responseCount
---------- -------------
2012-02-13 0
2012-02-12 4
2012-02-11 5
2012-02-10 8
2012-02-09 0
2012-02-08 7
2012-02-07 3
```

Comment: Note that I used count(Responses) instead of sum(Responses) because my test table has for each row a QuestionnaireID, DateAdded, and column of response text. Your data might require switching to sum(Responses)